# How to stop a process started by run.exec() in android

Tags: android

How to stop "ping"? The following code is the way I try, but It fail.

```
private class pingWifi implements Runnable {
           Process p = null;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*
         * WifiInfo info=mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo(); int
         * ip=info.getIpAddress(); String ips=Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
         */
        System.out.println("pingWifi runnable");
        String[] shell = new String[] { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", " " };
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

        shell[2] = "ping " + ipAddress;
        try {
            p = run.exec(shell);
            if (p.waitFor() != 0) {
                if (p.exitValue() == 1) {
                    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                    InputStream is = p.getErrorStream();
                    int c;
                    c = is.read(buff, 0, 1024);
                    System.out.println("ping error: " + new String(buff));
                }
            } else {
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
                int c;
                c = is.read(buff, 0, 1024);
                System.out.println("ping result: " + new String(buff));
                // wait for hardware
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
void stopProcess() {
        if (p != null) {
            p.destroy();
        }else{
            System.out.println("stopProcess: p==null");
        }
    }



    }
private pingWifi mpingWifi = new pingWifi();
    Thread wifiThread = new Thread(mpingWifi);
            wifiThread.start();
```

In the onPause I call mpingWifi.stopProcess(),the result is "stopProcess: p==null". And I still can find the ping process in the "ps" list.

I also think to use "pkill ping" command. but "pkill" command is not supported in Android shell.My target is the ping is not "stop" until "home or back" key event happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding back button press and calling Process.destroy() in it.

Example:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
p.destroy();
}
```

Comment: @kioboar Thank you for your reply. what is the p?

Comment: But I get "the p is null". I think "ping 192.168.11.3" this process always is running and don't return its point to p. So p is null. Is it right?

Comment: At where do you get p is null? Does " p = run.exec(shell); " execute successfully?

Comment: I have updated my question. You can check it again. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Judy Hmm I see you using ping -t. But -t requires an argument but you did not provide any argument after -t. Also, Android has the kill command instead of pkill but I think you need to be root in order to call kill on ping.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4629/discussion-between-judy-and-kikoboar)